# Early return in Vue setup script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Is it possible to have an early return in the Vue setup script?

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="error || !data">Fallback content...</div>
  <div v-else>Page content...</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// ...

const { data, error } = await fetchApi()
// Early return here? E.g., if (error || !data) return

// ...
// Lots of code which doesn't need to run if error. 
// E.g., calculation of variables only used in the page content.
// ...
</script>
```

Note: I'm coming from the React world and kinda new with Vue.

Comment: It's the same anywhere in JS. If you're not in function scope (actually you are with `script setup` but technically not) just use branching with if. This may be XY problem as the component uses suspense, this means that a parent is responsible for fallbacks. If it's not the case then you probably don't need suspense and won't have this problem

Comment: Create a separate component `<PageContent />` and place all *"Lots of code which doesn't need to run if error"* inside that component. If it doesn't get rendered, it's never run. Obviously, replace `<div v-else>Page content...</div>` with `<PageContent  v-else />`. That's the the common *"early return"* in Vue.

Comment: @Estus, are you referring to [`<suspense />`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html)? Or to the *"suspense"* pattern?

Comment: @tao Not sure about what's the pattern, but I mean suspense Vue feature, which `await` in script setup automatically forces to use. The alternative is to not block component rendering, load data after the comp was loaded and display it with v-if, as you suggested

Comment: The pattern existed before either React or Vue implemented them as core components: you have 2 (actually 3) templates: a loading one and data/error one(s). Displayed accordingly. That's what I understand when someone says "suspense pattern" in FE.

Comment: I think both suggested solutions (branching with if/else or creating sub components) are not very useful and would result in horrible/unmaintainable code. I'm also worried about the Typescript support.

Comment: What specifically would be wrong with subcomponents? The parent (the component you have now) handles getting data, handles errors, etc., and then the subcomponent is purely for displaying/using the data.

Answer (score 1):

you can throw an error:

```
const {data, error} = await fetchApi()
if(error || !data) throw new Error('your error message')
```

It prevent the rest of the code to run

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Nuxt 3 you can use [useFetch](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch) that returns `data`, `error` and `pending`.

So the code could be:

```js
<script setup>
import { nextTick } from 'vue';
const response = ref({});
onMounted(() => {
  nextTick(async () => {
    const { data, error, pending } = await useFetch('/api/foo');
    response.value = { data, error, pending };
    if (data) {
      // make long calculation
    }
  });
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="response.error || !response.data">Fallback content...</div>
    <div v-else>Page content...{{ response.data }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

See a working [replication](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-34fxwn?file=pages%2Findex.vue&initialpath=/)